# signing jars to be used over web start

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a java web start app that uses Swing and needs to allow a user to open a file local on their machine. My application is failing to run because it says that the the single jar I am trying to use is unsigned. I did however, sign it.

In my .jnlp file I am specifying security as:

```
<security>
    <j2ee-application-client-permissions/>
</security>
```

and I used the following commands to create the keystoare sign my jar file, validator.jar:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore mykeys -alias https://www.mydomain.com
jarsigner -keystore mykeys -storetype JKS validator.jar https://www.mydomain.com
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just use the FileOpenService. http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/FileOpenService.html

Comment: I seem to be missing the javax.jnlp package. Is this a seperate download in java1.6?

Comment: Nevermind, it needed to be added to my classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tom Since I only need to allow the user to open a file locally for processing, I decided to use the FileOpenService. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

do you have the APPLICATION.JNLP file that is the same (has the same exact content) of your jnlp file that is included in the signed jar?

it would be located in your resources/JNLP-INF directory.

also- are you using maven?

maven has plugins to help with signing jnlps

Comment: No I don't believe so. I have my validator.jar that I am deploying inside a WAR. The WAR contains the jnlp file. I don't have the jnlp file inside the validator.jar file. Should I also sign the WAR file?

Comment: Talking about maven and jnlp.. do you know of any standard procedure to copy the jnlp into JNLP-INF/ directory of the main jar? I use maven webstart plugin, and it looks like it does not support this.